# How to install the EPSON L210 Printer utility

Tags: printing, epson

Some additional details:

I can print and scan but I need to clean and align the printing heads. I have tried many solutions but none of them work.

When I try to run the following code according to instructions on  the EPSON website

```
# rpm -i epson-printer-utility-<Version>-<Architecture>.rpm
# dpkg `-i epson-printer-utility-<Version>_<Architecture>.deb`
```

I get:

> The file or directory does not exists

Comment: You likely should've edited this rather than creating a new question, but the <Version> and <Architecture> are likely supposed to be replaced with version and architecture specific to your system, or the combination of the printer and your machine. And the # at the beginning of each line may be commenting-out the script so it's ignored.

Comment: **I can print and scan** Does it mean you've already installed the printer? If that is the case, you probably should modify the question.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you have added the printer utility; if you have you should find it in your menu; to install it go here

http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=79180&DSCCHK=ee99825cf8dd051c99c59905b70420470967a26d

and click to download what will be epson-printer-utility_1.0.2-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb

as you click to download, your system should offer to OPEN the package; OPEN here means INSTALL so accept that offer;

otherwise it will end up saved in your Downloads folder; so find it and double-click it there; to install; it will create an icon in your MENU[image]